# How to deploy an edited node module package(local) to heroku without losing the changes?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

So, I have a situation where I needed to edit a node module package I'm using in my node app. Now, on deploying the app to heroku the changes are getting lost because it is getting that package from npm.

Please suggest a way other than publishing my own version of that package to npm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can :/
I have a bot deployed there and every time I wanna deploy some new changes everything gets lost. Probably you should check some external packages installed by Heroku.